# terraform retention policy not setting as expected

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Currently for DB's the basic/default retention policy is set by AZURE & I wanted to change to user specific values but not setting as expected.

Block of code goes like this

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "primary" {
  count                            = (var.is_primary == "true" ? 1 : 0)
  name                             = var.sql_database_name
  server_id                        = azurerm_mssql_server.app.id
  sku_name                         = "AAAAA"
  create_mode                      = "Default"
  zone_redundant                   = var.sql_zone_redundancy
  tags                             = var.resource_group.tags
  threat_detection_policy {
    state                          = "Enabled"
  }
  short_term_retention_policy {
    retention_days = 35
    backup_interval_in_hours = 12
  }
  long_term_retention_policy {
    weekly_retention = "P1W"
    week_of_year = 1
  }
}
```

Any configuration am I missing here..

Update : In logs it was updated that the database will be modified with below plan

```
~ long_term_retention_policy {
    ~ week_of_year      = 0 -> 1
    ~ weekly_retention  = "PT0S" -> "P1W"
      # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
  }

~ short_term_retention_policy {
    ~ retention_days           = 7 -> 35
      # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
  }
```

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: @coder can you please provide the error or blocker that you are facing?

Comment: @MarkoE  There is no error in the terraform script

Comment: @kavyaSaraboju  There is no error in the terraform script. That's what making me wonder

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code from my end and faced few  errors .But then changed the following arguments accordingly .

- The week of year has to be between 1 and 52. But it is given as 1
- And you have provided retention_days = 35 , its value has to be between 7 and 35.
- Zone redundant value can only be supported for Premium and Business Critical databases.

> And please note that backup_interval_in_hours  is only applicable to
> live databases.

Please note that the primary source database shouldn’t have higher SKU service tier than any secondary databases .So please check , if the is_primary value affecting the resource deployment as, it depends on few factors.

```
data "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "remotestatekavstr"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
 //location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  //account_tier             = "Standard"
 // account_tier             = "Premium"
 // account_replication_type = "LRS" 
}

data "azurerm_mssql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "ka-example-sqlserver"
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

 
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "test" {
  count                            = (var.is_primary == "true" ? 1 : 0)
  name           = "acctest-db-d"
  server_id      = data.azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
  collation      = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  license_type   = "LicenseIncluded"
  max_size_gb    = 5
  read_scale     = false
  sku_name       = "S0"
  zone_redundant = false

  short_term_retention_policy {
    retention_days = 35
    backup_interval_in_hours = 12
  }
  long_term_retention_policy {
    weekly_retention = "P1W"
    week_of_year = 1 
     }

 // tags = {
 //   foo = "bar"
 // }
}
```

[image]

**Reference:** [azurerm_mssql_database | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_database)

Comment: * Zone redundancy was set to false
* For secondary we are not providing the SKU name
* Provided the in-between values for week of year and retention_days
Result still same the changes are not reflecting

Is your changes reflecting in retention policy ?

Comment: Can you try placing  sensitive = true for the important confidential variables . Also refer [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28540) if it is the case

Comment: In some cases terraform tries to check if resource is already existing with values which are managed. if new changes doesn't match. Try to apply once, then change ,plan and apply the changes again.